# PushNamed issue: Type 'FillData' (a Statefulwidget) is not a subtype of type 'List<Object>'

Tags: flutter, push

I'm new in Flutter. I'm trying to push a List from NewData to FillData screen with `pushNamed`. But it said:

> The following _TypeError was thrown while handling a gesture:
> type 'FillData' is not a subtype of type 'List'

If i remove the comment in '/FillData', i receive null data instead. What should i do?

This is my code:

1. SettingNavigator

```
class SettingNavigator extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => Home(),
        '/NewData': (context) => NewData(),
//      '/FillData': (context) => FillData(),  (in comment)
}
      onGenerateRoute: (setting) {
        if (setting.name == '/FillData') {
          final ChartGroupData chartName = setting.arguments;
          final List<ChartGroupData> groupNames = setting.arguments;
          return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
            return FillData(
              chartName: chartName,
              gName: groupNames,
            );
          });
        }
        return null;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

2. NewData

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NewData extends StatefulWidget {
  List<ChartGroupData> groupNames;
  NewData({Key key, @required this.groupNames}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  NewDataStage createState() => NewDataStage();
}

class NewDataStage extends State<NewData> {
  TextEditingController _nameCtrl = new TextEditingController();

  var textFields = <Widget>[];
  var groupTECs = <TextEditingController>[];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    textFields.add(createCustomTextField());
  }

  Widget createCustomTextField() {
    var groupCtrl = TextEditingController();
    groupTECs.add(groupCtrl);

    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5, 0, 0),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(flex: 3, child: Text("Group ${textFields.length}")),
          Container(
            constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: 120, height: 60),
            child: TextField(
              controller: groupCtrl,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Center(child: Text("New Chart")),
        ),
        body: Container(
          alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
          constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                "Your chart name",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              TextField(
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                controller: _nameCtrl,
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 3,
                child: Container(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: textFields.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return textFields[index];
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 60,
                width: 120,
                child: RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: _onTapNext,
                  child: Text("NEXT"),
                  color: Colors.green,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: _onTapCreate,
          child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white),
          shape: CircleBorder(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onTapNext() {
    /// Push Groups name to FillData
    widget.groupNames = List<ChartGroupData>();
    for (int i = 0; i < textFields.length; i++) {
      var name = groupTECs[i].text;
      widget.groupNames.add(ChartGroupData(name));
    }
    print(widget.groupNames.toString());
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/FillData',
        arguments: FillData(
          gName: widget.groupNames,
          chartName: ChartGroupData(_nameCtrl.text),
        ));
  }

  void _onTapCreate() {
    setState(() {
      textFields.add(createCustomTextField());
    });
  }
}
```

3. FillData

```
class FillData extends StatefulWidget {
  final ChartGroupData chartName;
  final List<ChartGroupData> gName;
  FillData({Key key, @required this.chartName, @required this.gName})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  FillDataStage createState() => FillDataStage();
}

class FillDataStage extends State<FillData> {
  void _showDialog() {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text("Received Data"),
          content: Text(widget.chartName.toString()),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void _onTapPrintReceivedData() {
    print(widget.gName);
    print(widget.chartName);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Center(
          child: Text("Fill your Data"),
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _onTapPrintReceivedData();
            _showDialog();
          },
          child: Text("Print Data"),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

4. Class ChartGroupData

```
lass ChartGroupData {

  final String groupNames;
  ChartGroupData(this.groupNames);

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Group: $groupNames';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 problems with your code:

1- you cant user routes with onGenerateRoute, because now the app doesn't know where to go, to the widget that you didn't pass anything to (inside routes) or to the widget inside the onGenerateRoute.

2- arguments is a general object that you can put whatever you want inside of it, and doing this:

> final ChartGroupData chartName = setting.arguments; final

> List groupNames = setting.arguments;

passes the same value to two different objects, I solved this by doing the following (it's not the best but will give you a rough idea of what you should do)

- created a new object that contains the data to be passed:

  ```
  class ObjectToPass {
    final ChartGroupData chartName;
    final List<ChartGroupData> groupNames;

    ObjectToPass({this.chartName, this.groupNames});
  }
  ```
- changed FillData implementation:

  ```
  class FillData extends StatefulWidget {
    final ObjectToPass objectToPass;
    FillData({Key key, @required this.objectToPass}) : super(key: key);

    @override
    FillDataStage createState() => FillDataStage();
  }

  ...

  void _showDialog() {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text("Received Data"),
          content: Text(widget.objectToPass.chartName.toString()),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void _onTapPrintReceivedData() {
    print(widget.objectToPass.groupNames);
    print(widget.objectToPass.chartName);
  }
  ```
- to navigate to FillData you would:

  ```
  Navigator.pushNamed(
    context,
    '/FillData',
    arguments: ObjectToPass(
      chartName: ChartGroupData(_nameCtrl.text),
      groupNames: groupNames,
    ),
  );
  ```
- finally this is how your MaterialApp should look like:

  ```
  return MaterialApp(
    initialRoute: '/NewData',
    onGenerateRoute: (setting) {
      if (setting.name == '/FillData') {
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
          return FillData(
            objectToPass: setting.arguments,
          );
        });
      } else if (setting.name == '/NewData') {
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => NewData());
      }
      return null;
    },
  );
  ```

you can pass a list instead of the object I created and get your objects from it by it's index.

Comment: thank you, it works. i have pushed my list successfully. It's the toughest part in my project